# IE7 float bug? Menu won't float-right in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, css-float

I have a menu list that displays correctly on the most recent versions of IE, Safari, FF, and Chrome, but not in IE7. I've looked at similar posts here on StackOverflow, but the answers didn't help. The problem menu is at the top of http://skyambitions.massivemouse.com. It floats over to the left (rather than the right) and over top of the logo.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the menu ul {display: inline; float: right; rest of the declarations here}

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Do you mind explaining why that's necessary in IE7, but not in the other (more current) browsers?

Comment: one of the many inconsistencies of standards implementation i'm sure. generally if it's an ie 6/7 problem, it has something to do with incorrect implementation of the box model and hasLayout. anyways. if the answer worked, vote it up.